# Android MediaCodec: EGL_BAD_SURFACE, eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, egl

I am following the example of DecodeEditEncodeTest.java in bigflake.com/mediacodec
The only difference in my app is that I decode a real video file (instead of a chunk data in the memory), and encode to a real video file (instead of a chunk data in the memory)

The log shows the error happens when it does swapBuffers.

```
03-22 10:54:51.111: D/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): decoder output format changed: {height=240, what=1869968451, color-format=2141391875, slice-height=256, crop-left=0, width=320, crop-bottom=239, crop-top=0, mime=video/raw, stride=384, crop-right=319}
03-22 10:54:51.121: I/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info_encoder, = 0
03-22 10:54:51.121: D/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): no output from encoder available
03-22 10:54:51.121: D/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): surface decoder given buffer 0 (size=147456)
03-22 10:54:51.121: D/OutputSurface(5375): new frame available
03-22 10:54:51.121: D/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): awaiting frame
03-22 10:54:51.131: D/ExtractMpegFramesTest(5375): swapBuffers
03-22 10:54:51.131: W/Adreno-EGL(5375): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3526>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
03-22 10:54:51.131: E/InputSurface(5375): eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
```

From the error information, what kind of possibilities can be responsible for the error?

**[Update 1]**
In the original version of my code, I set the encoder with the desired parameters.
Now I use the same code from DecodeEditEncodeTest.java to determine the parameters.
Code is as below:

```
MediaFormat inputFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(trackIndex);
// ... 
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE));
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE));
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL));
```

When the program implements inputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE), it simply exits, go to finally block. It cannot be caught by "catch", so I could not print out the error information.

**[Update 2]**
OK, I found the reason. outputSurface was not correctly created.
The question in [Update 1] still holds.

Comment: Could be that the EGL context isn't set up right.  Are you missing a `makeCurrent()` somewhere?  If you're running this in the UI thread you may need to make the EGL context current more often, as the UI thread may be using GLES for its own rendering.

Comment: @fadden. Thanks. I use makeCurrent(), like in DecodeEditEncodeTest.java:  inputSurface.makeCurrent(); encoder.start();

Comment: @fadden, is it possible to provide an example code to decode, edit, encode a real video file in bigflake.com?

Comment: It *is* a real video file.  The fact that it's generated, rather than extracted with `MediaExtractor`, doesn't change a whole lot.  There are other examples that decode video from a file (the frame extraction test) and that encode video to a file (camera to mpeg test).  You can also take a look at Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) which does a lot of EGL surface juggling.

Comment: <DequeueBuffer:606>: dequeue native buffer fail: Out of memory, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
    W/Adreno-EGL(  279): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3692>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE   same errror
    E/SurfaceFlinger eglSwapBuffers(0x1, 0xb8edeae0) failed with 0x0000300d    
W/SurfaceFlinger: [xxComposer] Unexpected advanceFrame() in GLES state on GLES/MIXED frame
     E/SurfaceFlinger(  279): [xxxComposer] advanceFrame: no buffer, bailing out
    E/SurfaceFlinger(  279): [xxxComposer] failed pushing new frame to HWC: -12
    E/BufferQueue(23060): [xxComposerService] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!

Comment: This error only on Samsung note 3, How to resolve it? sure invoke makeCurrent on JNI

Comment: I resolved some issues on Note 3 by turning off hardware acceleration in the Manifest. Something to do with Snapdragon vs Mali.